# How can I align a group text with seperate Widgets

Tags: html, css

I want the text labeled

"I want this text aligned with the bottom widget
" to be aligned with bottom widget.

How do I achieve this? HTML ->

```
<div class="albums">
<iframe class="albumWidget" src="https://widgets.itunes.apple.com/widget.html?c=no&brc=FFFFFF&blc=FFFFFF&trc=FFFFFF&tlc=FFFFFF&d=&t=&m=music&e=album&w=325&h=370&ids=258634938&wt=discovery&partnerId=&affiliate_id=&at=10lumY&ct=" frameborder=0 style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;width:325px;height: 370px;border:0px; display=inline;"></iframe>

<h3>Only Built 4 Cuban Linx (1995)</h3>

<p>
"  Most cd's I buy, I get sick of in a few weeks or even days. However, this album is so perfectly balanced and groundbreaking that I get chills everytime I listen to it. When I listen to it, it just boggles my mind. " -- A customer
</p>
<p>
“ Beats by RZA are sharp like a razor.  ” -- A. Sidletsky
</p>
</div>

<div class="albums">
<iframe class="albumWidget" src="https://widgets.itunes.apple.com/widget.html?c=no&brc=FFFFFF&blc=FFFFFF&trc=FFFFFF&tlc=FFFFFF&d=&t=&m=music&e=album&w=325&h=370&ids=328405814&wt=discovery&partnerId=&affiliate_id=&at=10lumY&ct=" frameborder=0 style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;width:325px;height: 370px;border:0px;"></iframe>

<p>I want this text aligned with the bottom widget</p>
</div>
```

CSS ->

```
.albums { 

}
iframe.albumWidget {
  float:right;
  clear: right;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Here's a link to website so you can have look http://raekwon.gteaay.com/discs-baby

Here's a link to a screenshot that shows the website the way I need it to be http://raekwon.gteaay.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works! And it uses class (reusable, write once and apply class where needed), which the correct way to do it.

```
.albums { 
  position: absolute;
}
.reviews {
  float: left;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
.albumWidget {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

    <section class="albums">

    <section class="reviews">
    <h3>Only Built 4 Cuban Linx (1995)</h3>
    <p>
    "  Most cd's I buy, I get sick of in a few weeks or even days. However, this album is so perfectly balanced and groundbreaking that I get chills everytime I listen to it. When I listen to it, it just boggles my mind. " -- A customer
    </p>
    <p>
    “ Beats by RZA are sharp like a razor.  ” -- A. Sidletsky
    </p>
    </section>
    <iframe class="albumWidget" src="https://widgets.itunes.apple.com/widget.html?c=no&brc=FFFFFF&blc=FFFFFF&trc=FFFFFF&tlc=FFFFFF&d=&t=&m=music&e=album&w=325&h=370&ids=258634938&wt=discovery&partnerId=&affiliate_id=&at=10lumY&ct=" frameborder=0 style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;width:325px;height: 370px;border:0px;"></iframe>


    <section class="reviews">
    <h3>Only Built 4 Cuban Linx II (2009)</h3>
    <p>" Raekwon's sound takes listeners back to gritty Shaolin of the 1990s; however, the production does not sound like leftover beats from that era. Instead, it is a fresh, new take on NYC street life and drama. " -- Intellectualista </p>
    </section>
    <iframe class="albumWidget" src="https://widgets.itunes.apple.com/widget.html?c=no&brc=FFFFFF&blc=FFFFFF&trc=FFFFFF&tlc=FFFFFF&d=&t=&m=music&e=album&w=325&h=370&ids=328405814&wt=discovery&partnerId=&affiliate_id=&at=10lumY&ct=" frameborder=0 style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;width:325px;height: 370px;border:0px;"></iframe>


   </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

i do not know if this can help.. do check my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ayiem999/HFs2k/

```
.albums { 

}
iframe.albumWidget {
  float:right;
  clear: right;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

p{
float:right;
  clear: right;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


<div class="albums">
<iframe class="albumWidget" src="https://widgets.itunes.apple.com/widget.html?c=no&brc=FFFFFF&blc=FFFFFF&trc=FFFFFF&tlc=FFFFFF&d=&t=&m=music&e=album&w=325&h=370&ids=258634938&wt=discovery&partnerId=&affiliate_id=&at=10lumY&ct=" frameborder=0 style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;width:325px;height: 370px;border:0px; display=inline;"></iframe>

<h3>Only Built 4 Cuban Linx (1995)</h3>

<div>
"  Most cd's I buy, I get sick of in a few weeks or even days. However, this album is so perfectly balanced and groundbreaking that I get chills everytime I listen to it. When I listen to it, it just boggles my mind. " -- A customer
</div>
<div>
“ Beats by RZA are sharp like a razor.  ” -- A. Sidletsky
</div>
</div>

<div class="albums">

<iframe class="albumWidget" src="https://widgets.itunes.apple.com/widget.html?c=no&brc=FFFFFF&blc=FFFFFF&trc=FFFFFF&tlc=FFFFFF&d=&t=&m=music&e=album&w=325&h=370&ids=328405814&wt=discovery&partnerId=&affiliate_id=&at=10lumY&ct=" frameborder=0 style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;width:325px;height: 370px;border:0px;"></iframe>
 <p class="hi">I want this text aligned with the bottom widget</p>

</div>
```

Comment: I  want it to be aligned with top of the 2nd widget. Like the text by the 1st widget.

Comment: No, like the Other text which is **next** to the widget.

Comment: No :)  The "text I want next to 2nd widget" should align with the top of the 2nd widget. So that it looks like it belongs to the 2nd widget. I'll post a screenshot for you.

Comment: you should.. ur requirement not clear to me.. what is first and 2nd widget btw.. and the position to of the text..

Comment: The 1st widget is the one on top. And the 2nd is the one below. pretty self explanetory. Take a look at the original question, I have added a screen shot that should clear it up.

Comment: Did you add `<h3 style="margin-top: 200px;>`? I've already done that. And really it's more a "hack" than a solution. A ideal solution would be to add a class that I can apply to many elements.

Comment: if you dont like to do like that you can just used table.. with invisible border.. it more complex btw..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50615/discussion-between-chakotay-and-airi)

Comment: If anybody wants to see the intended way to align these elements, the you can take a look at http://raekwon.gteaay.com/disc-baby